# Using azure Ad group , role and attribute information to control user data access in we application

Tags: azure-active-directory, authorization, okta

We are creating a web app we will have data per  category. A user will have access to a certain category's data  only. Can user-category access information be stored in identity providers like azure active directory b2c or okta .. (some thing like different  groups per category) or should we just used identity provider for authentication and store access related information in database.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can store all of these in Azure AD B2C user attributes. And if something doesn't exist, you can always create a custom attribute.